# Сколько слогов в слове "смысл"?

Tags: фонетика

Moжно ли с чистой совестью утверждать, что слово "смысл" односложное? Если нет, то есть ли другие слова, в которых количество слогов больше количества писанных гласных? Что говорят по этому поводу авторитетные источники по русскому языку?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Смотря что считать слогом. Согласно [Википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3) (выделение моё),

> Слог — это минимальная фонетико-фонологическая единица,
>   характеризующаяся наибольшей акустико-артикуляционной слитностью своих
>   компонентов, то есть входящих в него звуков. **Слог не имеет связи с
>   формированием и выражением смысловых отношений. Это чисто
>   произносительная единица.** В слоге группируются звуки разной степени
>   звучности, наиболее звучные — слогообразующие, остальные — неслоговые.

То есть, если проще, всё сводится к тому, по какой метрике, собственно, измерять эту звучность. «Школ» слогоделения существует несколько, в вышеупомянутой статье дан хороший обзор основных. Давайте попробуем провести какой-то начальный анализ в рамках каждого подхода.

- *Экспираторная теория слога* Если совсем коротко, теория заключается в том, что сколько выдохов («сколько дрогнула свеча»), столько и слогов. Поднесите ладонь к лицу и произнесите «смысл» — в среднем «по палате» получится, скажем так, полтора слога; всё зависит ещё и от личных особенностей произношения — уровень экспрессии у всех разный, у некоторых на «cл» тоже получается слабый, но всё таки поддающийся детектированию выдох. Эта теория неоднократно подвергалась критике, было найдено множество контпримеров, так что она устарела.
- *Сонорная теория слога* под слогом понимает сочетание более сонорного (звучного) звука с менее сонорным. Тут мы опять попадаем в ловушку необходимости давать чёткие определения — что есть сонорность? Например, под это определение могут не попадать [звонкие шумные](http://www.km.ru/referats/79F5998AFB324194A44AEDF78E698575#). Тут филологи сломали немало копий вообще и в отношении русского языка в частности. Языковед Рубен Аванесов (чьи работы в рамках этой теории считаются наиболее проработанными) создал целую теорию о закономерностях подъёмов и падений звучания, которую нет тут смысла излагать всю, конечно, но согласно этой теории в слове «смысл» два слога, но может быть и один — смотря как произносить. Кстати, по иронии судьбы Аванесов большую часть своей жизни был практически глух, что нисколько не умаляет его лингвистических заслуг.
- *Теория [мускульного] напряжения* утверждает, что границей слога является те участки речи, при которых работа мышц артикуляционного аппарата максимальна. В рамках этой теории слово «смысл» всё-таки двухслоговое.

Я завершу этот далеко не полный список упоминанием того факта, что есть теории, пытающиеся в той или иной мере комбинировать подходы всех вышеупомянутых (и не упомянутых) школ.

От себя я замечу, что я не филолог, поэтому споры эти мне казались всегда очень умозрительными и даже ещё более бессмысленными, чем знаменитый спор ленинградской и московской фонетических школ о существовании звука «ы» в русском. Потому что у звукораспознавания, в отличие от слогоразделения, есть вполне понятный и «осязаемый» практический аспект.

Что касается других примеров таких «проблемных» слов, то «ау» и «сплав», упомянутые в той же статье в Википедии — хорошие кандидаты.

Comment: Ответ очень подробный и грамотный, но хотелось бы добавить, что официально слог таки один: произношение «смысъл», «метър» (я употребляю ер, естественно, в транскрипционном —« болгарском» — его значении) считается факультативным, а наличие слоговых сонантов в русском языке лингвистами не признаётся.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно традиционной системе, принятой в русском языке, количество слогов равно количеству гласных. Таким образом, в слове один слог.

Answer (score 0):

> есть ли другие слова, в которых количество слогов больше количества
>   писанных гласных?

Ну, также - в зависимости от того как произносить - "мяу". По крайней мере кошки мяукают односложно )
Ну, из заимствованных - модное нынче "ресепшн" - явно 3 слога.